# Hbase region Splits and Store File

Tags: hbase

I am new to hbase so excuse if i ask an odd question.
My doubt is :

1)When the region is split in hbase where is the storefiles in the region moved?

2)Does compaction takes place in Region or in HDFS?

3)Where is the store files in hbase stored in Region or HDFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

1> When you split the region, reference files are created for daughter regions. Accepting requests into the original region is stopped. This makes the user feel that region has been split. Necessary file structures are setup in the split directories set up parent region. Daughter region directories are created in these folders. After successfully completion of this, this two region directories are moved to the table directory. Now, the .META. is updated and parent region is deleted.

2> Compaction takes place in region. Compaction is done by monitoring the Store files. When there are too many small Store files, they can be compacted into a large file.

3> Store files are in HRegion. Refer the above image for a clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the store files are not moved anywhere at first.  Instead reference store-files are created pointing to the original store files.  After a compaction new store files are created.

Check [this](http://hortonworks.com/blog/apache-hbase-region-splitting-and-merging/) out for details